# NMDS display and point symbol questions (vegan in r)

Tags: r, statistics, vegan, mds

I've successfully produced NMDS plots (monoMDS, bray-curtis, 3 dimensions, local model). Each point represents an animal and their diet composition.

I have two questions:

(1) how do I change the symbology of points to show 2 levels (a or j) within 1 column (Life stage) on the NMDS plot?!

(2) How should I show 3D NMDS, I can't get the 3D orgl- functions to work on the 3D plot. Should I just make a few plots showing different dimensions in 2D? Looking for thoughtful ideas.

The code used:

```
    plot((BC.NMDS.length.corr), choices = c(1, 2), type = "points",
          xlim = c(-2.0, 2.0),las = 1, ylim = c(-1, 1), 
          xlab = "NMDS Axis 1", ylab = "NMDS Axis 2",mgp = c(3.25, 1, 0), 
          cex.lab = 1.35, cex.axis = 1.25)

    with(DATA, 
         points(BC.NMDS.length.corr, Class, draw = "points",col = "gray0", 
                show.groups = "Adult",label = TRUE, lty = 1, lwd = 2))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please write an example of the code you are using? This will provide us more information and it would be easier for us to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an example of what you want with the default example of the package:

```
     # Load library
       library(vegan)
     # Load data
       data(dune)
     # Compute the distance
       dis <- vegdist(dune)
```

Specify if you want a 3D plot, the representation of the three dimensions

```
     # Run monoMDS
       m <- monoMDS(dis, model = "loc", k=3)

     # The 3D representation
       plot(m)
     # Load library for 3D representation
       library(scatterplot3d)
```

Coordinates are in `m$points`; each column referring to each dimension.

```
     # Graphical representation
       scatterplot3d(x=m$points[,1], y=m$points[,2], z=m$points[,3])
```

Additionally, if you want to colour the plots depending on a factor, you can specify `color=A`, where `A` is a numeric value where groups are codified.

Comment: So, you are interested in colour your individuals by `site`. For this `scatterplot3d(x=m$points[,1], y=m$points[,2], z=m$points[,3], col = factor(site, labels=c(1,2,3)))`

Comment: You should set `asp = 1` (requires **scatterplot3d** version 0.3-40) in ordination plots. Alternatively, you can use **vegan3d** package and `ordiplot3d()` function that takes automatically care of many things, including the aspect ratio and reading ordination result objects.